# Magento mutliple languages - domain or subfolder?

Tags: magento

I am currently redeveloping an ecommerce site to use magento. 
Curreently it's on www.mysite.co.uk as we only sell in the UK

(www.mysite.com 301 redirs to .co.uk)

We have www.mysite.fr - which will cater for France (therefore prices in EUR

My question is - is it best to have two separate domains, or should I use subfolders?

Like:

www.mysite.com - English
www.mysite.com/fr/ - French

.. and of course redirect www.mysite.fr to www.mysite.com/fr/

Comment: Magento has this all built in to have one instance of magento running and multiple domains/stores and views. No need for sub folders at all. Simply go into the admin and create a new store view for your current web-site. Give it a name of FR. Then go to System Configuration in the admin, and top left you should be able to select the store view to be the new FR one where you can then override the default currency, domain name, shipping country and any other admin option you have. This will allow you to have www.mysite.fr without any redirects, same products, categories, design etc.

Comment: Read http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work for a full explanation as to how to setup magento with multiple languages, websites, and domains. My personal preference on this is to use the domain name of the country. So French users will always visit yoursite.fr and german users will see yoursite.de as the domain.

Comment: I agree with you @AshleySwatton - that'd be my preference too - i wanted to check it was a) possible b) recommended :)

Comment: The answer below is also a good guide to read as it shows the pros and cons for each approach. If you can afford the domains and have them, then I would always go for this approach mainly for geo targeting reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a SEO question than a strict Magento one, since both is perfectly right on a strict technical way.

There is much debate around what to do domain versus subfolder, both having their up and down side.
This site have a table going with the pro and con which will be really hard to reproduce here due to its presentation design : http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.be/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html